# Why is my DeleteTodos function behaving so oddly in my TodoList App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a simple todolist app on react and I came up this problem. I could write the code necessary for adding todo items to the list defined in the state and displaying it but when it comes to deleting items off of the list from the click of the button adjacent to every todoitem, all todoitems get removed from the list except the first item. what should I do. Here's the code :

The TodoList(parent) Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AddTodos from './AddTodos';
import DisplayTodos from './DisplayTodos'
import "./TodoList.css";


class TodoList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            myList: [],
            searchField: ''
        }
        this.DeleteTodos = this.DeleteTodos.bind(this)
    }

    onSearchChange = (event) => {   
    this.setState({searchField: event.target.value})

}


    addTodo = () => {

        if(this.state.searchField !=="") {
        var newItem = {
            text: this.state.searchField,
            key: Date.now()
        }

        this.setState({myList: this.state.myList.concat(newItem)})
        this.setState({searchField: ""})
        console.log(this.state.myList)

        } else{
            alert("Please enter something")
        }

    }

    DisplayList = () => {
        const ListItems = this.state.myList.map((listitem, i) => {
            return(
                <li key={listitem.key} onClick={(i) => this.DeleteTodos(i)}>{listitem.text} <button>Delete</button>
                </li>
                )
        })

        return ListItems;
    }

    DeleteTodos = (i) => {
        i.preventDefault()
        this.setState({myList: this.state.myList.splice(i, 1)})
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div className="TodoList">
                <AddTodos addTodo={this.addTodo} onSearchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
                <DisplayTodos DisplayList={this.DisplayList}/>
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

The DisplayTodos Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AddTodos from './AddTodos';
import DisplayTodos from './DisplayTodos'
import "./TodoList.css";


class TodoList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            myList: [],
            searchField: ''
        }
        this.DeleteTodos = this.DeleteTodos.bind(this)
    }

    onSearchChange = (event) => {   
    this.setState({searchField: event.target.value})

}


    addTodo = () => {

        if(this.state.searchField !=="") {
        var newItem = {
            text: this.state.searchField,
            key: Date.now()
        }

        this.setState({myList: this.state.myList.concat(newItem)})
        this.setState({searchField: ""})
        console.log(this.state.myList)

        } else{
            alert("Please enter something")
        }

    }

    DisplayList = () => {
        const ListItems = this.state.myList.map((listitem, i) => {
            return(
                <li key={listitem.key} onClick={(i) => this.DeleteTodos(i)}>{listitem.text} <button>Delete</button>
                </li>
                )
        })

        return ListItems;
    }

    DeleteTodos = (i) => {
        i.preventDefault()
        this.setState({myList: this.state.myList.splice(i, 1)})
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div className="TodoList">
                <AddTodos addTodo={this.addTodo} onSearchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
                <DisplayTodos DisplayList={this.DisplayList}/>
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

AddTodos Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AddTodos from './AddTodos';
import DisplayTodos from './DisplayTodos'
import "./TodoList.css";


class TodoList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            myList: [],
            searchField: ''
        }
        this.DeleteTodos = this.DeleteTodos.bind(this)
    }

    onSearchChange = (event) => {   
    this.setState({searchField: event.target.value})

}


    addTodo = () => {

        if(this.state.searchField !=="") {
        var newItem = {
            text: this.state.searchField,
            key: Date.now()
        }

        this.setState({myList: this.state.myList.concat(newItem)})
        this.setState({searchField: ""})
        console.log(this.state.myList)

        } else{
            alert("Please enter something")
        }

    }

    DisplayList = () => {
        const ListItems = this.state.myList.map((listitem, i) => {
            return(
                <li key={listitem.key} onClick={(i) => this.DeleteTodos(i)}>{listitem.text} <button>Delete</button>
                </li>
                )
        })

        return ListItems;
    }

    DeleteTodos = (i) => {
        i.preventDefault()
        this.setState({myList: this.state.myList.splice(i, 1)})
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div className="TodoList">
                <AddTodos addTodo={this.addTodo} onSearchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
                <DisplayTodos DisplayList={this.DisplayList}/>
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DeleteTodos = (i) => {
    i.preventDefault();
    let arr = [].concat(this.state.myList);
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({myList: arr});
}
```

The `splice` function will change the array and return a new array of deleted items, so you should declair a variable to copy `myList`, and change the variable. **What you do will change the state.**

Comment: Okay , So I tried your code and this is what happened. I could delete items off of my display list by the click of the button next to the item but only the topmost item gets removed by the click of any button corresponding to any item. How can you you explain this ?

Thanks for the answer anyways.

Comment: @Ram_KS  In `DisplayList` ,  `onClick={(i) => this.DeleteTodos(i)` =>`onClick={this.DeleteTodos.bind(this, i)}`.

Comment: `i` will be `undefined` or the length of `myList` (I'm not sure about that, you can check by adding `console.log` to your `DeleteTodos` function to see)